# R igraph add.edges() with attributes

Tags: r, attr, igraph, edges

Assign during add.edges() an attribute, like width:

```
g <- add.edges(g,c(from,to), attr= width <- 1 ) 

Error message:
please supply names for attributes
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign it a named list:

```
g <- graph.adjacency(matrix(0,2,2))
g <- add.edges(g,c(1,2),attr=list(width=10))
```

With the code you used you assign `1` to a variable `width` and then assign the value of `width`, i.e. `1`, to the argument `attr`.

Comment: Thanks: works! But change c(1,2) to c(0,1). Because igraph starts counting with '0'

Comment: Not anymore in the latest version of `igraph`. The `igraph0` package now does that.

Comment: Really, I just updated it via istall.packages('igraph'). Still the old style of  labeling.

Comment: Really, see http://igraph.sourceforge.net/relnotes-0.6.html. Do you have the latest version of R?